# Can I assign a value for one parameter

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using crystal reports 2008. I want to generate a report for which i will get one value from one subreport and i want to pass this value as a parameter so that i can include this value in the sql command.
For eg.

From my subreport i will get customerkey and i want to pass this value in the sql as 
{?customerkey}

Sql is 'select card_number from customers where customerkey={?customerkey}' 
For this i created parameter in the command and added like this.

But what my problem is this customerkey is getting from subreport(using shared variable).If i get a value customer_key from subreport how will i assign this value to {?customerkey}. I tried like assighning this value but i dont want to popup {?customerkey}this value as a parameter.

Can anyone help? Please

Answer (score 0):

So you want the data shown in the main report to be based on a parameter passed to it from a subreport? I don't think this is possible - the Report Processing Model (described [here](http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?p=52)) states that SubReports are in 'Pass 2', while data retrieval is in 'Pass 1'. This means that the parameter prompt will always appear first.

You might instead be able to have the main report contain TWO subreports, the first of which is used to retrieve the parameter and the second uses it. That can get very messy, especially when dealing with page headers and footers.